# Boost::Variant - "no matching function for call"

Tags: c++, templates, boost-variant

There are a ton of questions regarding this problem but none of them seem to be a solution to my problem. I don't think this is really a Boost::Variant issue; I'm pretty sure that I'm just using templates in an incorrect manner. I was able to strip down the code so you can compile it and see the problem for yourself, it's pretty simple - I keep getting a 'no function call' error from gcc even though it appears to be right there. I'm probably doing something stupid but I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> Data;

struct A
{
    template <typename T> T data() { return boost::get<T>(m_data); };
    private:
      Data m_data;
};

struct B
{
   template <typename T> T data() { return m_a.data(); };
   private:
     A m_a;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `m_a.data<T>();`?

Comment: This code alone does not generate compiler error (at least in Visual Studio 2010, but I think it will not generate an error in any conforming compiler). To show the error you should actually call the `B::data` function somewhere. For example in `main` add a variable of `B` and call `data` on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Asha noted in a comment you should write:

```
template <typename T> T data() { return m_a.data<T>(); };
```

in `struct B`.

It is needed because template parameters are not deducted automatically based on return type (only based on arguments).

Comment: When I woke up this morning I knew what the problem was right of the bat. This was just one of those times I was working way too many hours and started made a really stupid mistake. I just wish it wasn't on such a easy problem because I knew better.